# Where is the taskbar Windows icon located in?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

I want the location of the Windows logo in Windows 10 that I can edit. My intention is to change the default Windows 10 icon. (Start Menu icon)

Comment: Look at Resource Hacker and the MRU files.  I do not think you can change this icon - just hide it with a third party start app

Comment: Which icon is that? The Start button?

Comment: ya it is the start button

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier to use a third-party tool such as [Open-Shell Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu), which not only lets you replace the stock MS Start Button image, but enables you to change its dimensions, show it in different states (unselected, selected), align it, etc.

[image: Custom Start Button]

[image: Open-Shell Menu Start Button Settings]

An immense amount of work has gone into these apps, *replacing* the standard Start Menu and adding *many* customizable features.